# Twitter Follow Me Button Broken on Small Screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, screen-size

I am trying to add a follow me button to a Bootstrap nav bar where I ran into an issue.  When the screen is greater than 768px, the button appears as normal.  But when the width is smaller and the button is loaded, the button says Follow without an account (@example).

[image: Broken Twitter Button]

---

The button appears correctly is the screen is loaded in the larger dimensions and then sized down to a width of below 768px.

[image: Working Twitter Button]

---

I know that the navbar dropdown should not break the button based on the fact that it works in full screen mode.

To see exactly what is going on, the site is http://votemohamadandsean.com.

---

So the question becomes:  What do I need to do to make sure the button loads correctly on small screens, such as mobile?